# Setting Up Listener for 3rd Party Mac App Window Resize

Tags: macos, appkit

I'm looking to develop an app that overlays a transparency overtop an existing window in MacOS. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to have the transparent window automatically translate and scale with the underlying window.

Is there a way to setup an event listener so that every time a particular 3rd party app's window is resized, my app will be notified and can resize the transparency?

If no cross platform solution exists, a solution in Swift would be preferred. Thanks.

Comment: See [How can my app detect a change to another app's window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853833/how-can-my-app-detect-a-change-to-another-apps-window) and [Can an Obj-C AXObserverCallback be converted to Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401278/can-an-obj-c-axobservercallback-be-converted-to-swift)

Comment: @Willeke Thank you for the relevant links. I've briefly perused them and they seem promising. I'll be sure to review them more carefully.